# Convert modal to div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a modal and I would like to make it as a static div (without any button to close or open) a simple div.
I am new to CSS and JS. I am using bootstrap. Do I need to modify javascript or css

https://github.com/amoffat/bootstrap-application-wizard
http://demos.creative-tim.com/wizard-demo-register

Please see the link above, I hope I am able to put it clearly now.

Comment: So, to clarify, you want to convert a Bootstrap modal to a div that is not a modal? So just do that. Remove everything that makes it a modal. Maybe I'm not understanding the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the modal classes from the div and it will behave as a simple div